# Is there a better python equivalent of mapKeysWith?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Haskell has this great function, mapKeysWith. Over the keys of a map, it applies some transform, combining the data object with a given function should a collision now exist. I created the example code below, which is pretty verbose. Is there a more pythonic way?

```
def mapKeysWith(combineF,op,mp):
    ret = {}
    for it in mp:
        if op(it) in ret:
            ret[op(it)] = combineF(ret[op(it)],mp[it])
        else:
            ret[op(it)] = mp[it]
    return ret

z = {1:2,3:4,10:11}
mapKeysWith(lambda x,y: x+y,lambda x: math.floor(x/10),z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible alternatives are the following:

```
import math
from functools import reduce
from collections import defaultdict


def map_keys_with(combine_f, op, mp):
    ret = {}
    for it in mp:

        if op(it) in ret:
            ret[op(it)] = combine_f(ret[op(it)], mp[it])
        else:
            ret[op(it)] = mp[it]
    return ret


def map_keys_with_setdefault(combine_f, op, mp):
    ret = {}
    for key, value in mp.items():
        ret.setdefault(op(key), []).append(value)

    return {key: reduce(combine_f, values) for key, values in ret.items()}


def map_keys_with_defaultdict(combine_f, op, mp):
    ret = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in mp.items():
        ret[op(key)].append(value)
    return {key: reduce(combine_f, values) for key, values in ret.items()}


z = {1: 2, 3: 4, 10: 11}
print(map_keys_with(lambda x, y: x + y, lambda x: math.floor(x / 10), z))
print(map_keys_with_setdefault(lambda x, y: x + y, lambda x: math.floor(x / 10), z))
print(map_keys_with_defaultdict(lambda x, y: x + y, lambda x: math.floor(x / 10), z))
```

**Output**

```
{0: 6, 1: 11}
{0: 6, 1: 11}
{0: 6, 1: 11}
```